# Cant Remove Event Listener App State React Native

Tags: react-native, event-listener

I try to using app state listener in multiple screen. But it seems not remove listener properly.
In my case, I have app state listener in Home screen and Order Screen. App state listener in Home screen is not remove properly.

This is my app state listener in Home screen,

```
const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  appState.current = nextAppState
  setAppStateVisible(appState.current)
  if (nextAppState === 'active') {
    checkConnection()
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange)
  checkConnection()
  return () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange)
  }
}, [])
```

This is my app state in Order Screen,

```
const _handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState) => {
  appState.current = nextAppState
  setAppStateVisible(appState.current)
  if (nextAppState === 'active') {
    permissionFirebaseIos
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange)
  return () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange)
  }
}, [])
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If you are using react-navigation you should notice that stack don't unmount so your listeners never will removed.

Comment: Yeah, I use react navigation, so in this case, i cant use app state in different screen, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can with useFocusEffect hook from react navigation
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/
Its the same as useEffect but when the screen get focused/defocused

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function YourScreen() {

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      AppState.addEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange)

      return () => AppState.removeEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange);
    }, [])
  );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in my case, I need to execute function every time user come from background. 
But your code will execute every time user open that screen, so I think it will not work for my case.

Comment: So the solution is put the listener in index or app. and update your things via context or redux